# Why Z={0,1,-1,2,-2,..} space as (R,usual topology) subspace has infinitely many connected components?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

Why $Z=${0,1,-1,2,-2,..} space as $(R,$usual topology) subspace has infinitely many connected components?

Connected component of topology space is called every connected subset that is not included  in other connected subset.

And I know that topology space is called connected if it can't be written union of two non-empty non-intersecting open subsets.

Maybe it is silly question but really can't think of a way to use definition to prove that it has infinitely many connected components.

Comment: Hint: start with a far simpler question: $W=\{0,1\}$ with the same topology. Which of the four possible subsets is connected?

Comment: @ancientmathematician {0} and {1}?

Comment: yes, so the component of $0$ is $\{0\}$ and the component of $1$ is $\{1\}$. Now generalise.